# selenium python a click in a cookie doesn't work

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

i try to click a button cookie, but doesn't locate element. with linux works but not with windows.

my code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'chromedriver.exe')

url = "https://www.lachainemeteo.com/meteo-france/previsions-meteo-france-aujourdhui"
driver.get(url)
sleep(2)

btn = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"sc-1epc5np-0.dnGUzk.sc-f7uhhq-2.coEmEP.button.button--filled.button__acceptAll").click()
```

where is the probleme, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here's a command that worked for me:

```py
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.button__acceptAll").click()
```

I used `By.CSS_SELECTOR` with `"button.button__acceptAll"`.

Easy to verify from the console.

[image]

For reliability on slower page loads, this is better:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
# ...
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.button__acceptAll")
    )
).click()
```

Because this alert only appears for me when I set the browser's locale code to `fr`, I would consider adding a `try`/`except` block around the code. Wait for the alert to appear for up to 5 seconds, and if it does, close it, otherwise continue:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
# ...
try:
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.button__acceptAll")
        )
    ).click()
except Exception:
    pass
```

Comment: doesn't work for me arfff

Comment: I updated the solution with the reliable way:

``WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.button__acceptAll"))).click()``

Comment: doesn't work, i have a timeout exception

Comment: Note that this alert ONLY appears when the web browser's locale is set to ``fr``. I didn't see it from the US until changing the browser's locale code.

Comment: i search a solution, with linux all code of my script works, the problems is just with my system windows

Comment: If the test is going to be running from locales where the alert doesn't show up, I would add an ``if`` statement or a ``try``/``except`` block around that alert.

Comment: i have change with united state but dosn't work, time out exception stay here

Comment: thx for your help, i continu to found a solution

Comment: I updated the solution with the correct ``try``/``except`` block to use.

Comment: ok thx, it's language

Comment: i have add an argument when open the web site

Comment: options.add_argument("--lang=en")  # and work, thx Michael

Answer (score 0):

with just this line and it's ok, thx for your help **Michael**, it's work now. with my system linux chrome is in english, and windows my chrome in french, you are god

```
options.add_argument("--lang=en")
```